# how to make maven war:explode do not pack a jar file

Tags: maven, war, exploded

I'm new to maven.
I'm now working on a multi module maven project, when i use maven war:exploded ,it will packaging classes files to WEB-INF/lib/***SNAPSHOT.jar.
Is there any way to leave the classes files under WEB-INF/classes , for when java file changes, there is no need to replace the whole jar file?

Thanks

Comment: Why? Is replacing the jar file too slow?

Comment: For regularly when i debug my program, the logs says the jar cannot be replaced, and i didn't change method signature or add/del methods.